# Class method parameter type based on generic class type

Tags: typescript

```js
class Route<T> {
  path: string;

  constructor(path: string) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  getLink(params: T) {
    if (!params) {
      return this.path;
    }

    return `${this.path}/${params.join('/')}`;
  }
}


const routeA = new Route<{ id: number }>('/something/amazing');

// should not be possible
routeA.getLink();

// only this should be valid
routeA.getLink({ id: 1 });
```

Hi - I would like to have a class Route that takes a generic parameter T (params). Each Route might have some params or none at all.

It should then be possible to call `routeA.getLink()` and have its parameter be typed correctly.

```
const a = new Route('index'); // takes no parameters
a.getLink() // only this is valid
a.getLink({ something: 1}) // invalid

const b = new Route<{ id: number }>('post'); // takes no parameters
b.getLink() // invalid
b.getLink({ id: 1}) // valid
```

How do I type this?

Some help would be really appreciated :)
Thanks!

Comment: What is the issue now? Do you want the param to be number or string only?

Comment: I need the `getLink()` method to take only params that i defined on new `new Route<T>`

but it should also be possible that a route doesn't have any params, e.g `getLink()` should only be possible for `new Route<null>()` or similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function overloads and a default of `null` for `T` to ensure that a certain overload to only be valid for a certain `this`:

```
class Route<T = null> {
    path: string;

    constructor(path: string) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    getLink(this: Route<null>): string;
    getLink(this: Route<T>, params: T): string;
    getLink(params?: T) {
        if (!params) {
            return this.path;
        }

        return `${this.path}/${params.join('/')}`;
    }
}


const a = new Route('index'); // takes no parameters
a.getLink() // only this is valid
a.getLink({ something: 1 }) // invalid


const b = new Route<{ id: number }>('post'); // takes no parameters
b.getLink() // invalid
b.getLink({ id: 1 }) // valid
```

Another solution would be to declare two constructor signatures a generic one and a non generic one, each returning a different type signature:

```
class RouteImpl<T> {
    path: string;

    constructor(path: string) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    getLink(params?: T) {
        if (!params) {
            return this.path;
        }

        return `${this.path}/${params.join('/')}`;
    }
}

const Route: {
    new (path: string) : { 
        path: string,
        getLink(): string;
    }
    new <T>(path: string) : { 
        path: string,
        getLink(params:T): string;
    }
} = RouteImpl;

const a = new Route('index'); // takes no parameters
a.getLink() // only this is valid
a.getLink({ something: 1 }) // invalid



const b = new Route<{ id: number }>('post'); // takes no parameters
b.getLink() // invalid
b.getLink({ id: 1 }) // valid
```

Comment: Why not just `getLink(this: Route<null>): string;  getLink(params: T): string;  getLink(params?: T) { ... }` without conditional types?

Comment: @jcalz you are right, coupled with a default of `T = null` also works, intelissense still broken though ..

Comment: The second example works like a charm, thank you! @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: @jcalz the `null` version allows the call `a.getLink(null)` which should not be a big deal .. but I think the conditional version works better as it removes that version. Although neither version works with intelisense :(

Comment: I can't reproduce any problem with IntelliSense... it shows me `getLink()` with overloads.  What specifically are you seeing?

Comment: @jcalz I think intelisense didn't catch up with me, indeed the null version shows `getLink` as expected. Edited the answer. THe conditional version does not show `getLink`, only `path`